# How to create "On this day in history" query

Tags: databricks

I'm using Databricks and I have a table with a list of event from various years.  I want to return the event most recent to today's date from each year.  For example,

Today's date is 6th May and my table is thus:

| Year (int) | Date (date) | Event (str) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2021-08-04 | Ate apple |
| 2021 | 2021-04-16 | Flew plane |
| 2020 | 2020-10-11 | Swam 100 miles |
| 2020 | 2020-03-07 | Did backflip |
| 2020 | 2020-01-01 | Tidied room |
| 2019 | 2019-09-30 | Found 10 pence |
| 2018 | 2018-02-22 | Lost 10 pence |

So I would want to return:

**On this day in history your most recent achievements were:**

| Year | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2021-04-16 | Flew plane |
| 2020 | 2020-03-07 | Did backflip |
| 2018 | 2018-02-22 | Lost 10 pence |

Is there a neat way of doing this?...and by neat I mean, without creating extra columns or tables i.e. by comparing CURRENT_DATE to my Date field.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Also, why store the year separately if it's already part of the date?

Comment: @mustaccio I didn't really know where to start but I've worked out how to do some regexp_extract() on CURRENT_DATE and my Date field and then compare months and days to get the all rows before today in each year but I'm not sure how to limit it to the most recent in each year?  I didn't make the table - the year is there just because.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use regexes to manipulate dates, [I don't think](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#date-timestamp-and-interval-functions).

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving what you want might be to use the [window function `row_number()`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/row_number.html) to order matching event dates within each year (window), then pick only the most recent date each year.

```sql
-- Use a common table expression to pre-select and order dates we want
with past_events as ( 
   select 
      Date, Event, 
      -- within each year, order by the day since the beginning of that year
      -- in the descending order, and assign row numbers accordingly
      row_number() over (partition by year(Date) order by dayofyear(Date) desc) rn
   from some_table
   -- only pick days from each year in the past that's no later than today
   where dayofyear(Date) <= dayofyear(current_date())
   and   year(Date) < year(current_date())
) 
select year(Date), Date, Event
from past_events
where rn = 1 -- now pick only first (most recent) date of each year
order by Date desc
```

This is "paper code" as I have no way of testing it with Databricks, but it should give you the basic idea.

---

You may need to [quote column names](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-identifiers.html#delimited-identifiers) if `Date` or `Event` happen to be reserved words in Databricks.